# How to use Sass and CSS Modules with create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sass, create-react-app, css-modules

I am using FileName.module.scss to style my react elements like so:

```
// this is my component
import React from "react";

import Aux from '../../hoc/Aux';
import classes from './Layout.module.scss';

const layout = (props) => (
    <Aux>
        <div>Toolbar, SideDrawer, Backdrop</div>
        <main className={classes.Content}>
            {props.children}
        </main>
    </Aux>
);

export default layout;
```

This is my SCSS:

```
.Content {
    margin-top: 72px;
    color:red;
}
```

I don't know why but the scss is not being applied to my main element, any ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You will have to install node-sass in order to work with scss files.

**npm install node-sass --save-dev**

Your code seems to be alright as post React 16.8 you can use css and scss modules without configuring webpack. I would suggest you check your version of React first. If you are using a version of React < 16.8 then you would have to eject and configure your webpack in order to use css and scss modules.

Comment: node-sass has been deprecated. Use the dart sass instead - `npm install sass`

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-sass-stylesheet)

There is also an option of SASS pre-processing using `node-sass-chokidar` and add `"sass:watch": "node-sass-chokidar <scss directory> -o <compiled css directory> --watch"` to your `scripts` to monitor changes.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the latest `create-react-app` which support sass by default, and I assume `Layout.module.scss` is a scss file name.

use `import './Layout.module.scss';` instead of `import classes from './Layout.module.scss';`

then you may directly call the className

```
<main className={Content}>
 {props.children}
</main>
```

Comment: This can create the problems in the form of variable shadowing (for example, if you had `button` defined in your component, and the styles defined for class called `.button` in your scss).

Answer (score -1):

I see you're following the same course as me. To fix the issue just use `classes.content` instead of `classes.Content`

Answer (score -4):

Dont do it... it's a pain of huge build times after your Project grows as described [here](https://medium.com/jsdownunder/webpack-build-performance-pitfall-of-using-sass-with-css-modules-ba32f89efdcb)...

Comment: This is interesting. I had no idea.