# i import css file in my react js file but it doesn't show in browser

Tags: css, reactjs, import, frontend, jsx

in signup directory there is two file name signup.jsx and styles.css i import css file in my jsx file import styles from "./styles.css";
but it doesn't load on browser.

## this is signup.jsx

```
import { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./styles.css";

const Signup = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({
        firstName: "",
        lastName: "",
        email: "",
        password: "",
    });
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
        setData({ ...data, [input.name]: input.value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        try {
            const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/signup";
            const { data: res } = await axios.post(url, data);
            navigate("/login");
            console.log(res.message);
        } catch (error) {
            if (
                error.response &&
                error.response.status >= 400 &&
                error.response.status <= 500
            ) {
                setError(error.response.data.message);
            }
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className={styles.signup_container}>
            <div className={styles.signup_form_container}>
                <div className={styles.left}>
                    <h1>Welcome Back</h1>
                    <Link to="/login">
                        <button type="button" className={styles.white_btn}>
                            Sing in
                        </button>
                    </Link>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.right}>
                    <form className={styles.form_container} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        <h1>Create Account</h1>
                        <input
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="voter_id"
                            name="voter_id"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={data.voter_id}
                            required
                            className={styles.input}
                        />
                        <input
                            type="password"
                            placeholder="password"
                            name="password"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={data.password}
                            required
                            className={styles.input}
                        />
                        
                        <input
                            type="password_confirmation"
                            placeholder="password_confirmation"
                            name="password_confirmation"
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            value={data.password_confirmation}
                            required
                            className={styles.input}
                        />
                        {error && <div className={styles.error_msg}>{error}</div>}
                        <button type="submit" className={styles.green_btn}>
                            Sing Up
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Signup;
```

## this is styles.css

```
.signup_container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.signup_form_container {
    width: 900px;
    height: 500px;
    display: flex;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%),
        0px 3px 4px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 14%), 0px 1px 8px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
}

.left {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #3bb19b;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.left h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 35px;
    align-self: center;
}

.right {
    flex: 2;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.form_container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

.form_container h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.input {
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    width: 370px;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #edf5f3;
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.error_msg {
    width: 370px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #f34646;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

.white_btn,
.green_btn {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 12px 0;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 20px;
    width: 180px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.green_btn {
    background-color: #3bb19b;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

## this is dir structure

[dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HzFI.png)

## this is unexpected output

[output][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TR1Ro.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make a basic import like this :

```js
import './styles.css'
```

And remove all "styles." occurences on className and replace it like this :

Before

```js
 <div className={styles.signup_container}>
```

After

```js
<div className={"signup_container"}>
```

Or you could even use it like following :

```js
<div className={style["signup_container"]}>
```

Or if you want you can also use scss and scss modules then use it like you do now.
See [How to use Sass and CSS Modules with create-react-app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686089/how-to-use-sass-and-css-modules-with-create-react-app)